# Merging pdfs using aws lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, pdf

I currently have a nodejs project that generates pdfs using puppeteer. 
I now want to merge the generated pdfs into a single pdf. There are npm libraries like easy-pdf-merge and pdfmerger available. 
The issue is we would want to host our project in AWS Lambda. Can these libraries run in a Lambda as a nodejs application given they require Java 6 or higher? If not, what would be the best approach to merge pdfs within a lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to use [layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html). You can start with a node.js lambda and add a layer for your java needs.

You can check [this github repo](https://github.com/mthenw/awesome-layers) for publicly available lambda layers. There's one for java 11.